# The RGB vectors for white and red color are same for this image (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]

I was working with this picture in Matlab to detect the color of the circles. This is a 512 by 512 jpeg image.

I am finding the centers of circles using imfindcircles, then I am taking the R, G, B components of some points near the center of each circle to detect color.

But, I am confused because, for both the red and white circles, I find that the R, G, B components are same [239 227 175].

I am new to image processing, so can anyone explain what's actually happening here.

Comment: You have to show us some actual code....I'm guessing that you're selecting the beige background pixels (because of incorrect indexing) rather than the actual circles

Comment: You are sampling outside. That is the color of the background

Comment: Don't put your code on pastebin, edit your question and add it here (formatted by indenting it)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`centers` output](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html#outputarg_centers) of `imfindcircles` gives the coordinates of the centers in x/y coordinates and you need to index into your image using row/column coordinates so you need to be sure to reverse the two columns when indexing into the image

```
centers = imfindcircles(IM);

center1 = IM(centers(1,2), centers(1,1),:);
center2 = IM(centers(2,2), centers(2,1),:);
```

Presumably you are not doing this because you are instead sampling pixels from the background which obviously result in the same RGB values for the centroids.

**Update**

It appears that *actual* issue is that you are casting the location of the centroids to a `uint8` to make it an integer value so you can then use it as an index. The maximum integer representable by `uint8` is   `255` and the number of rows and columns in your image is large than `255` (and so are the centroids) so they will get truncated to `255` resulting in the wrong pixel being sampled.

Rather than using `uint8`, just use `round` to round the centroids to their nearest integers

```
cX = round(centers(n_c,1));
cY = round(centers(n_c,2));
```

Comment: @cgb How are you creating `cF_EDGE`?

Comment: cf_EDGE is returned by edge() function, this part works as I have already detected the circles successfully.

Comment: @cgb Are you first converting your image to grayscale before calling `edge`? or what? Please show your complete code

Comment: Yes, okay. I am formatting my complete code and showing it to you.

Comment: @cgb Updated with the real issue